# Read Images from system or url using google apps script in google sheets and post image to an API

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to SO.

I am trying to hit an api using put request to upload the images and I wanted to do it using google sheets and google apps script. I am able to add images from url to the sheet but not to the api because it accepts only .png/.jpeg format and I think currently it is going in blob format. Not sure.

Can anyone please help me on how to send image to api using google apps script and sheet.

I am able to get success response using postman when in params I type image as key (filetype) and then upload image from device.

Here is some code that I am using to achieve the above:

```
function insertImageOnSpreadsheet() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('Enter URL Here');
  var binaryData = response.getContent();

  // Insert the image in cell A1.
  var blob1 = Utilities.newBlob(binaryData, 'image/png', 'MyImageName');
  Logger.log(blob1)
  
      var apiHeaders = 
    {
      "Content-Type":"application/json",
      "Authorization":"Enter Token here"
    }
    var formData= '{"image": "'+blob1+'"}'

    var eventApiResponse = callApi('Enter API Here',"put",formData,apiHeaders,"insertImageOnSpreadsheet");
    Logger.log(eventApiResponse)
 
 
  sheet.insertImage(blob1, 1, 3);
}

function callApi(targetURL, method, formData, headers,functionName) {
  var options = {
    "method": method,
    "payload":formData,
    "headers":headers}
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(targetURL, options);
  return response;
 }
```

API :
**livestream.com/developers/docs/api/#update-event-logo-poster**

Somebody pleaasseee help

Comment: In order to correctly understand about your current situation, can you provide the specification of the API you want to use and the current error message?

Comment: The API says unsupported file type. So I assume that my code is sending blob.
API accepts a png file in the image key

Comment: Thank you for replying. For example, when you send the file as the byte array instead of the blob, what result will you get? It's like `var formData = Utilities.newBlob(binaryData, 'image/png', 'MyImageName').getBytes()` or `var formData = JSON.stringify({image: Utilities.newBlob(binaryData, 'image/png', 'MyImageName').getBytes()})`. If those were not the direct solution, I apologize.

Comment: Although I cannot still understand about the specification of the API you want to use, from `The API says unsupported file type`, for example, how about base64?

Comment: API will only accept Images in png and jpeg, no other file format or format like base64 or blob will be accepted. Error - {"code":415,"message":"HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type"}

Comment: @Tanaike, This is the API https://livestream.com/developers/docs/api/#update-event-logo-poster

Comment: @Tanaike hi, can you please help?

Comment: Thank you for replying and providing the official document of the API you want to use. I apologize for my late response. I could confirm your updated question just now. From the official document, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direct solution, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to request of ["Update Event Logo (Poster)"](https://livestream.com/developers/docs/api/#update-event-logo-poster) using Google Apps Script.

#### Modification points:

- When I saw the sample curl command of "Update Event Logo (Poster)", it is as follows.

  ```
    curl -X PUT \
      -u [API_SECRET_KEY] \
      -F logo='@<image file location>;type=<image type>' \
      --header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
      'https://livestreamapis.com/v3/accounts/18855759/events/5201483/logo'
  ```

  - In this case, the basic authorization is used. And it seems that the request body is required to be sent `{"logo": "data"}` to "files" using `multipart/form-data`.
  - In order to send the file data with `multipart/form-data`, it is required to create the request body.

    - In this case, the request body is created with the byte array, because the binary data is included.
- In your script,

  - I cannot understand about `"Authorization":"Enter Token here"`. But from the sample curl command, I thought that "API_SECRET_KEY" was not encoded with the base64.
  - At the sample curl command, `"Content-Type":"application/json"` is not used.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified it becomes as follows.

```
const url = "###";  // Please set URL you want to use. It's like "https://livestreamapis.com/v3/accounts/18855759/events/5201483/logo".
const API_SECRET_KEY = "###";  // Please set your API_SECRET_KEY
// var binaryData = UrlFetchApp.fetch('Enter URL Here').getContent();
const binaryData = DriveApp.getFileById("### fileId ###").getBlob().getBytes();  // Modified

let data = "--xxxxxxxxxx\r\n";
data += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"logo\"; filename=\"sample.png\"\r\n";
data += "Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n";
const payload = Utilities.newBlob(data).getBytes()
  .concat(binaryData)
  .concat(Utilities.newBlob("\r\n--xxxxxxxxxx--").getBytes());
const options = {
  method : "put",
  contentType : "multipart/form-data; boundary=xxxxxxxxxx",
  payload : payload,
  headers: {authorization : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(API_SECRET_KEY)},
};
const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
console.log(res.getContentText())

var blob1 = Utilities.newBlob(binaryData, 'image/png', 'MyImageName');
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
sheet.insertImage(blob1, 1, 3);
```

- In my environment, I could confirm that the request of above modified script is the same with that of the curl command.
- In this case, it supposes that `UrlFetchApp.fetch('Enter URL Here');` returns the binary data of the image of PNG or JPEG. Please be careful this.

#### Note:

- Please use this script with enabling V8 runtime.
- In this case, the line breaks in `data` is important. So please be careful this.
- When your "API_SECRET_KEY" and URL are not correct, an error occurs. Please be careful this.
- From the sample curl command, I proposed `authorization : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(API_SECRET_KEY)` as the authorization header. But if `API_SECRET_KEY` is the same with `"Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(API_SECRET_KEY)`, please try to modify to `authorization : "API_SECRET_KEY"`.

#### Reference:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)

Comment: Hey, Thank you for the answer but there is a problem. When I try to use a google drive link that contains the image it gives this

Exception: Request failed for https://livestreamapis.com returned code 400. Truncated server response: {"code":400,"message":"Command failed: convert-im6.q16: not authorized `/tmp/uploadBeb5ea5532e2663e047ac3a813acb175' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) (line 30, file "Code")

Comment: @Ponnay Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your error message, it is considered that the reason of the error might be due to the authorization and/or the URL. In my proposed answer, the request is the same with the sample curl command of the official document. So can you confirm your parameters for authorizing again. Because I cannot test this. I apologize for this. By the way, can you show your current script in your question? By this, it might think of the issue. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: Hey, All I am doing is I am inserting a  google drive image link in the third line of the answer that you have shared. I think the data is coming from google drive in terms of text/html when we are doing getContent(), that's why it is giving the mentioned error.

Comment: @Ponnay Thank you for replying. I would like to confirm your current situation. In your current error is from `var binaryData = UrlFetchApp.fetch('Enter URL Here').getContent();`? Is my understanding correct? From `I am able to add images from url to the sheet`, I had thought that `UrlFetchApp.fetch('Enter URL Here')` can be worked fine. If my understanding is correct, can you provide the sample URL? Because I cannot understand about `Enter URL Here`. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id={fileID}

Comment: @Ponnay Thank you for replying. From your replying, I could understand that the file was in the Google Drive, and the file is yours and/or the publicly shared. For this, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direct solution, I apologize.

Comment: @Ponnay Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.